# Замена пикселя на прозрачный

Tags: python, opencv

Как можно изменить пиксель на белый, а на прозрачный?

```
img2 = cv2.imread('image.png')
img[1, 1] = [255, 255, 255]
```

Решил вот так

```
img2 = cv2.imread('image.png')
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
img2 = cv2.imread('image.png')
img[1, 1] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: а какой цвет у прозрачного ?

Comment: ну у него нету цвета по идее

Comment: попробуйте цвета  RGBA . Формат RGBA похож по синтаксису на RGB, но включает в себя альфа-канал, задающий прозрачность элемента. Значение 0 соответствует полной прозрачности, 1 — непрозрачности.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290096/python-opencv-add-alpha-channel-to-rgb-image

Comment: попробовал - закрасилась вся картинка прозрачяным

Comment: Так посмотрите какого значения компонента A у остальных пикселей выставилась, может в 0 и её надо вручную тогда в 255 проставить по всей картинке, кроме нужного пиксела.

Comment: сделал уже, всем спасибо